# How to proxy requests to local IP

Tags: rust, hyper

So this is a simple proxy service on `localhost:8000`, how can I make all clients using the proxy think that the domain example.com is locally on the machines IP (`192.x.x.x`)

Like if you added the domain to the hosts file. All other request should just do the actual request.

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tower::make::Shared;

use hyper::{ service::service_fn, Body, Client, Request, Response, Server };

async fn log(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
    let path = req.uri().path();
    let host = req.uri().host();

    if host.unwrap() == "example.com" {
        // make example.com's ip be localhost:3000
    }

    handle(req).await
}

async fn handle(req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
    let client = Client::new();
    client.request(req).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let make_service = Shared::new(service_fn(log));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8000));
    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_service);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        println!("error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

`Cargo.toml`

```toml
[package]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
hyper = { version = "0.14.25", features = ["full"] }
tokio = { version = "1.26.0", features = ["full"] }
tower = { version = "0.4", features = ["full"] }
```

Comment: You need DNS server and it shouldn't be a part of this application, changing hosts files it's like changing DNS record where some domain is pointing out. So question is not about Rust but about networking and how to resolve domain like `example.com` to own IP address

Comment: but it needs to be, isn't there a way to do this? It needs to open a proxy and bind the domain to the local address. On multiple devices